# Mapping Two Continuous Sorted Integer Sets onto One Integer Set

Tags: algorithm, integer, set

I am trying to map two continuous sorted integer sets (with potentially differing number of items) to a single continuous sorted integer set preserving linear spacing.

e.g.
A: {1,2,3}
B: {1,2,3,4}
could map onto
C: {1,2,3,4,5,6,7}
by
A: {1->1, 2->4, 3->7} and
B: {1->1, 2->3, 3->5, 4->7}

It's pretty each to do these by hand, but I'm having trouble generalizing.

Decomposing the problems, I need to find (1) the number of buckets in the output set and (2) the input -> output mapping

My solution provided here:

> // There are LCM(|A|-1,|B|-1)+1 buckets in output C
>
> int numBuckets = LCM(
>   A.Count()-1, B.Count()-1 ) + 1;
>
> // Map elements in A to buckets in
>   output C
>
> for (int i = 0; i < A.Count(); i++)
>   {
>       mapping.Add(A.ElementAt(i),
>       (i*((numBuckets - 1)/(A.Count() -
>       1))).ToString());  }

Comment: What is the input and what is the output of the requiring algorithm?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Your mapping is not injective since the 3 in A maps to 7 in C, and so does the 4 in B. It's not surjective, since nothing maps to 2. Presumably there's something wrong with the mapping A: {1->1, 2->2, 3->3} and B: {1->1, 2->2, 3->3, 4->4}, but what? If permitted, this is easily generalizable :-)

Comment: Oh, if you mean that the ends of the ranges have to map to the ends of C, then C has the special property that length(C)-1 is divisible by both length(A)-1 and length(B)-1. If it wasn't, you couldn't do it.

Comment: I provided an input and output. The problem is that I need two integer sets of differing lengths to map to a common third integer set while preserving linear spacing, and, as Steve aptly added, having matching endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the size of set C is *|C| = Nc* and for set A, *|A| = Na*. Then, if you want to map *A* to *C*, let the first elements map to each other and then skip elements by

```
floor( (Nc-1)/(Na-1) )
```